# Can not run a Git Repo in Android Studio

Tags: git-clone, git-repo

I cloned a GitRepo but can't run it. The file is just too complex and I'm pretty noob. I wasn't able to find anyone who suffers the same problem. So could you help me how can I run this repo ?
Here is the ss of program.[image: I cloned the repo and this is the screen I get. What am I supposed to do ? I'm aware it's probably very simple to solve but I kepp watching Indian videos and none of them explains !]

Well I tried to add configuration but could not succed.I'm not very proficient at this and don't even know much ways to try.

Comment: The app android-accessibility seems to be multi-service: the first one is available both for Java and Kotlin programming languages, a counter and the global action bar. Running the whole app means running the three modules separately.

Comment: And what should I do Davide ?

Comment: I suggest to consider each service (module) apart, understand which technology is used (framework, language, build tool) and read the documentation about that technology.